# Flurry 4.2.1 for iOS fails to link

Tags: ios, flurry

I updated to the new Flurry 4.2.1 library on iOS.  However, when I build my project, I get the following linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
...

What is the likely cause of this error?  I have already made sure that all the required frameworks are installed.  Are there any special linker flags that I need to set?

Comment: Did you forgot to add SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: All four necessary frameworks, MediaPlayer.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework, UIKit.framework, CoreGraphics.framework are present.

Answer (score 0):

You've included all the required frameworks, and this issue is not expected to arise. Can you please write to support@flurry.com with further details of your issue?

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: similar issue here, any resolution?